# Problema ao tentar resolver um desafio

Tags: python

Preciso da ajuda de vocês para escrever um pequeno código que seja capaz de receber um número, bem como o seu índice e retornar o próximo elemento da sequência.

O problema é que eu ainda não consegui descobrir a lógica que está por trás disso:

[image: Enunciado do desafio]

[image: Testes do desafio]

O código que eu escrevi é o seguinte...

```
def next(a,i):
  """
  1,0,2,−1,3,−2,4,-3,5,-4
  """
  if i%2 == 0:
    return 1 + 1*i//2
  else:
    return  1 + (-1)*i//2
print(next(17, 31))
```

Comment: lucasbbs, favor editar sua pergunta, inserindo o código que você tentou fazer e especificando suas dificuldades.

Comment: @Solkarped, okay... Eu já editei o código
O problema está no último caso de teste

Comment: Não sei se entendi o critério, mas enfim, meu chute: https://ideone.com/jG2qE9 - Mudando de assunto, não conheço essa plataforma, mas já não gostei. Ela mistura 2 problemas: um é a programação em si, a outra é tentar adivinhar a regra maluca que gera os números. Se fosse para ensinar somente programação, o correto - na minha opinião - seria explicar a regra, pois aí a pessoa foca somente em escrever o algoritmo. Mas ao transformar num joguinho de adivinhação, eu acho que acaba prejudicando o aprendizado (mas sei lá, eu não sou professor, posso estar errado...)

Comment: Concordo com você @hkotsubo... Ainda mais é claro que a minha solução também satisfaz o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a sua função recebe `ai` e `i` como parâmetros, o mínimo que podemos esperar é que a expressão que definirá o próximo valor dependa desses dois valores.

Pelos exemplos fica mais claro que os valores dos parâmetros estão diretamente ligados ao resultado.

```
next(1, 1) = 0 ... 1 - 1 = 0
next(-1, 4) = 3 ... -1 + 4 = 3
next(-4, 10) = 6 ... -4 + 10 = 6
...
```

E por essa ligação podemos ver que se `i` é ímpar, nós subtraímos os dois valores para obter o próximo termo da sequência; já se `i` é par, basta somá-los.

Logo:

```py
def next(ai, i):
  signal = 1 if i % 2 == 0 else -1
  return ai + signal * i

assert next(1, 1) == 0
assert next(-1, 4) == 3
assert next(-4, 10) == 6
```

Se não for muito fã do `if` para definir o sinal, pode fazer a expressão equivalente utilizando potenciação, pois `(-1)**i` será negativo para `i` ímpar e positivo para `i` par:

```py
def next(ai, i):
  return ai + (-1)**i * i
```